# how to put a Cookie into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I'm trying to store an array for cookie, but I get the following error:

**Warning: setcookie() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given**

How can I actually put an array to a cookie?

EDIT2: I Edited the code, and I it does store cookie array now, but I've got a HUGE problem though. It does not override the values from first submission if the size of second array is smaller.

Example. first submission array[1206,0402], second submission array[0402]. but the outcome is then [0402,0402] which is wrong.

```
function cuukko($var,$val){
    setcookie($var,$val,time()+60*60*24*365);
}

function preg_DW($var){
    global $isset;
    if ($isset&&is_array($_POST[$var])&&sizeof($_POST[$var])>0){
        $C=0;
        foreach ($_POST[$var] as $key => $value) {
            $val[$C]=trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/',' ',preg_replace('/[^\d\w\s\(\)\[\]]+/','',$value)));
            cuukko($var."[".$C."]",$val[$C]);
            $C++;
        }
    } elseif (isset($_COOKIE[$var])) $val=$_COOKIE[$var];
        return (sizeof($val)>0)?$val:array();
}
```

Edit 3: The question has been resolved. The code in use now:

```
function cuukko($var,$val){
    setcookie($var,$val,time()+60*60*24*365);
}

function preg_DW($var){
    global $isset;
    if ($isset){
        $C=0;
        if (is_array($_COOKIE[$var]))
        foreach($_COOKIE[$var] as $key =>$trash)
        setcookie("{$var}[".$key.']', '', time()-60*60*24*365);
        if (is_array($_POST[$var]))
        foreach ($_POST[$var] as $key => $value) {
            $val[$C]=trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/',' ',preg_replace('/[^\d\w\s\(\)\[\]]+/','',$value)));
            cuukko($var."[".$C."]",$val[$C]);
            $C++;
        }
    } elseif (isset($_COOKIE[$var])) $val=$_COOKIE[$var];
        return (sizeof($val)>0)?$val:array();
}
```

Comment: Cool, but I how would I retrieve it then? :-)

Comment: @AlexLunix and probably `base64_encode()` that, owing to the possibility of breaking the `;` delimiters in a cookie.

Comment: base64_encode() hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm......... that doesn't ring the bell for me :-) I would really appreciate some example or scetch code for posting/ retriving. (assuming array is simple 1D array, and has couple of values, but variable in size.

Comment: Use the respective decode functions to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answer

You can store cookies using array syntax and read them as a multi-dimensional arrays:

```
setcookie('array[key]', 'value');
$var = $_COOKIE['array']['key'];
```

Your code would look like this:

```
for($val as $key=>$value)
  setcookie('vals['.$key.']', $value, time()+60*60*24*365);
```

### Multi-Dimensional Arrays

You can also store multi-dimensional arrays the same way:

```
setcookie('array[key1][key2]', 'value');
$var = $_COOKIE['array']['key1']['key2'];
```

### Clearing the Cookie

When you need to clear out the cookie, there are multiple methods; the longest being:

```
for($_COOKIE['array'] as $key=>$value)
  setcookie('array['.$key.']', '', time()-60*60*24*365);
```

The easiest and most preferable way is this:

```
setcookie('array', '', time()-60*60*24*365);
```

### Conclusion

Cookies allow arrays to be stored using standard array syntax. Storing a multi-dimensional array is also standard syntax.

To destroy a cookie with an array value, use the same syntax as for a normal cookie, either over the whole array or on each specific element.

The [documentation on `setcookie()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) goes over this.

Comment: @user1125062 edited. you have to parse `$val` into each element.

Comment: yeah I understand, I've done it so. It actually seems to work...
But the problem is that it does not overwrite the array...
For example if I submit the array that is smaller second time, there are still values from the first submission. And I cannot accept this behaviour

Comment: @user1125062 edited again. It uses standard cookie-deleting syntax.

Comment: Thanks, the first method works, setcookie('array', '', ...) doesn't.
What about substructed time? Do we actually need to set time when removing the cookie?

Comment: nevermind, it looks like a normal practice according to the documentation. I should have read it before doh ! :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to use serialize() and unserialize to store cookie data in one cookie, or json_encode(). Although standard array syntax behaves like an array, you are actually setting multiple cookies to make it work, which seems kind of wasteful. So, to use PHP documentation's own example

```
// set the cookies
setcookie("cookie[three]", "cookiethree");
setcookie("cookie[two]", "cookietwo");
setcookie("cookie[one]", "cookieone");

//On next pageload $_COOKIE['cookie'] = array ('one' => 'cookieone', 'two'=>'cookietwo', 'three' => 'cookiethree');
```

You have just set 3 cookies.

```
$array = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
setcookie('cookie', serialize($array);
//On next pageload
$array = unserialize($_COOKIE['cookie']);
```

You have set one cookie instead of three with the same data.