# Show last 5 recently view pages

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying the last 5 pages the user viewed on my site to them in a sidebar. Here is the code I am working with:

```
function curPageURL() {
$pageURL = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$pageURL .= ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != "80") ? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
return $pageURL;
}

$currentPage = curPageURL();
// $_SESSION['pages'] = $currentPage;
$_SESSION['pages'][] = $currentPage;
if (count($_SESSION['pages']) > 10) {
array_shift($_SESSION['pages']);
if (isset($_SESSION['pagehistory']) && count($_SESSION['pagehistory']) > 10) {
array_shift($_SESSION['pagehistory']);
echo '<h2>Page History</h2>
<ul>';
foreach ($_SESSION['pagehistory'] as $page) {
echo '<li><a href="'.$page.'" class="link">'.$page.'</a><li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}
}

$_SESSION['pagehistory'][] = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

// var_dump($_SESSION); // enable this to show the $_SESSION-arrays made above
```

When I use this code though nothing appears on my page. So basically I would like to show the user the last 5 pages they have viewed on my site and also like to show the page name not the urls.

Comment: "nothing appears on my page" not even the <li> tags?

Comment: Is `session_start();` indeed loaded and are you calling the `curPageURL()` function?

Comment: No not even the li's show up.

I've included the session_start(); to the code and still nothing. How can I tell is curPageURL() is being called?

Comment: I don't know, it's declared in `$currentPage = curPageURL();` so this tells me you've a function of that name that is supposed to be firing up something.

Comment: Well I tried to print out $pageURL and I get nothing. I'm not sure if that is helpful.

Comment: Sorry it didn't add the first part of my code before. Edited my question to include it.

Answer (score -1):

You could have a cookie that holds the names of recent pages.

[Cookie array for Recently Viewed - need to extract data from array and cap cookie to 5 IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600325/cookie-array-for-recently-viewed-need-to-extract-data-from-array-and-cap-cooki)

Comment: Why cookie? Sessions are better, server side and user can't edit them